# Array subscript in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, gcc

I have been looking for related GCC document which allows to declare something like this.

```
unsigned int subs = 10;
unsigned int array1[subs];
```

I'm aware such declaration is valid and work using gcc. I would like to get the relevant GCC document that specifies it's okay to declare.

Thanks,

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html ?

Comment: Is also valid in C99

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the OP doesn't care how they are implemented.

Comment: @iharob: Duplicate means that the other question is a superset and also provides the answer to this.  Which it does.  The accepted answer has a link to the documentation and additionally shows what the compiler produces.  The fact that this question doesn't ask for the second part doesn't make it deserve a duplicated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [6.9 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> As an extension, GCC accepts variable-length arrays as a member of a structure or a union. For example:
>
> ```
>     void
>     foo (int n)
>     {
>       struct S { int x[n]; };
>     }
> ```

Comment: I don't think this is the question.

Comment: @iharob: As requested in the question, this is the "relevant GCC document that specifies it's okay to declare".

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Declaring-Arrays)

> Another GNU extension allows you to declare an array size using
>   variables, rather than only constants.